# views are no published since I add custom elements for Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using the asp mvc template with dotnet core 6 preview 3.

Since I update to preview 3 (from preview 2) views are no longer published when I publish the site. Not better with preview4. **Even from a fresh template Views are not published.**

The directories Views and Areas are not even present in the publication.

There is no views.dll generated, and when I upload the publication to a sever I get a blank page when connecting to the site. In event viewer there is an error saying that `index.cshtml` can't be located.

I just can't imagine where to look for. Right now I copy and paste the Areas and Views directories to the server. I'm sure there is better to do.

----- EDIT 1

To restore my project behavior I had to add the following lines to my csproj:

```
<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
<CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
```

Comment: `since I add custom elements for Identity`,you mean only when you `add custom elements for Identity` views will not be published,or since you use preview3 views will not be published?

Comment: @YiyiYou yes that's what I meaned. But since I do more test and it doesn't seem to be related. The point is the migration from `Preview 2` to `Preview 3`.